# How can I parse xml file that is not in utf-8 in PHP with simpleXML?

Tags: php, xml, encoding, utf-8, simplexml

I am using simpleXML in PHP to fetch xml file.
The thing is that xml file's encoding is not in utf-8. It is in euc-kr.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="euc-kr" ?>
```

So, if I used the simpleXML to fetch the data, the text which is not in english, just crash. (but it correctly prints structures and everything...its just that text in Korean crash) 
Is there anyway that I can set encoding for simpleXML?

OR is there anyway that I can change the xml file to encoding with utf-8??

I just tried using str_replace('euc-kr','utf-8',$data) to change the words, but that does not seem to change the original file types. Because it causes an error like

```
Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding ! Bytes: 0xB0 0xB3 0xC6 0xF7
```

How can I resolve this problem? By the way, I have no permission to change the contents of the xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to get the same charset out, I would use DomDocument.  But if you want simplexml, you could load it through `DomDocument` then convert to simplexml:

```
$dom = new DomDocument('1.0', 'euc-kr');
$dom->load('file.xml'); // or loadXml($string);
$simple = simplexml_import_dom($dom->documentElement);
```

Then when you're done, just `$dom->save($filename);`...

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the solution.

```
$data = str_replace('euc-kr','utf-8',$data);
$data = iconv('euc-kr', 'utf-8', $data);
```

above codes have solved the solution.